# Download a folder from mediafire python

Tags: python, mediafire

I need some more storage for the current application I am using, so I thought I would host it on mediafire and then download and delete files at and after usage. Is there any way I could do this without using selenium?

Just in case you need the structure of the folder i'm downloading: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/1z3vk56tf787k/ImageBasedAttendance

Comment: MediaFire has an [API](https://www.mediafire.com/developers/) and, from the looks of it, a [Python library wrapping it](https://github.com/MediaFire/mediafire-python-open-sdk).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Didn't notice that, Ill take a look

Comment: @SilvioMayolo ```def fetchFilesMedia():
  response = api.file_get_links('ryi378twwdsrwsn')
  normal_download_url = response['links'][0]['normal_download']
  response = requests.get(normal_download_url, stream=True)
  with io.open("/home/runner/ImageBasedAttendance/records", 'wb') as fd:
      for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
          fd.write(chunk)``` I use that and it results in the whole pages html